# code for sries and sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, matlab

I want to know Matlab code for the following equation:

$$u_0(t)=t \\
u_i(t)=  u_{i-1}(t)+ \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} u_{j}(s)u_{i-1-j}(s).$$
for $i=1,3,4,....$

I wrote this one code. but is is not run. I know the problem is setting index. but I don't know why. 
syms t 
for j=1:4
    if  j==1
          u(j)=t;
    else
            sumf=0
            for i=1:(j-1)
                f=(u(i))*(u(j-1-i))
            sumf=sumf+f
            end
            u(j)=u(j-1)+sumf
        end
end

Comment: You might be able to accomplish this tidily with the `conv` (convulution) function in MatLab. See for example here: http://matlabtricks.com/post-3/the-basics-of-convolution

Answer (score 1):

```
syms u t
u = {}
u{1} = t;
for k = 2:10
  u{k} = u{k-1};
  for j=1:k-1   u{k} = u{k} + u{j}.*u{k-j};  end
end
expand(u{10})
```

Comment: I appreciate you for your helping.

Comment: Now, if I want to add the sentence:$\int_0^t \int_0^u e^{2s} u_{i-1}(s)ds du.$ to the this equation, what can I do. because I added int(int(exp(3*v)*u{k},0,s),s,0,t); and syms s v;  to the program but I was wrong.

Comment: @T.bashiri try with a simpler example, and see how it works. For example syms u t a;  u = exp(t); int(u,t,0,a);

Comment: but it is double integration. and also the limitations of integrals are variables

Comment: @T.bashiri come on... For example `syms t s u x; u = t^2; int(int(u,t,0,s),s,0,x)` works perfectly.

Comment: yes, you are right, thank you so much for your time

Comment: dear friends, 
I have completed the above code:
"clc; clear all; close all;
syms t u x s
n=6;
for j=2:n
 u(1)=1/10
   g=0
 for i=1:(j-1)
  f=u(i)*u(j-i)
  g=g+f;
 end
 u(j)=u(j-1)+int(g,0,t)+int(u(j-1),0,t)+g+int(int(exp(1/9*x)*u(j-1),x,0,s),s,0,t)
end
usum=0
for j=1:6
    usum=usum+u(j)
end
h=taylor(usum)
%t=0:0.1:15;
ezplot(h,[0,10])"

But now the problem is that this does not run for higher orders(high value for n). For instance, for n=20 it does not work. 
I appreciate you help me solve the problem.

Comment: Try using `expand` otherwise it won't simplify `t(t^2)+t^3` and (maybe) will need much more memory.

Comment: No,I tested expand. It does not solve the problem. Because I want to see the solution be Taylor series. expand shows as exponential.

Comment: Even when I don't use Taylor and only write ezplot(usum,[0,10]), it does not work for higher order for instance for n=15. but for n<7 its ok.

Comment: dear friends, now if I want to know, for instance, what is the value of $u_{10}(t=1)$. which code I have to write?? Its my pleasure help me.

Comment: make your own research 
'evaluate syms matlab'